# Using SVM with Linear Kernel in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, svm

I want to use the SVM algorithm with RBF kernel. I tried using the sklearn library but as my dataset is 100k it's been running for last 2 days. I couldn't think of any optimization/parallelization to do in sklearn. So, now i'm thinking of using spark SVM with RBF kernel. I couldn't find any api call in pyspark for SVM. Does anyone know about any Pyspark API for rbf kernel?

Thanks

Comment: In the official doc - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-classification-regression.html#linear-support-vector-machine

Comment: this seems to be linear svm and not kernelized svm with rbf kernel